# Android: Dynamic Textview (Linear Layout) doesn't show up on runtime

Tags: java, android, xml

i have another problem. I searched like the whole google and even stackoverflow but i don't find a solution for my problem.

I want to create TextViews dynamic on runtime with a linear layout (i also tried relative layout).

This is my code:

```
public class TurnierActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private final static String TAG = "Turnier";
    public View recentView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_turnier);
        recentView = findViewById(R.id.txt_welcome);
        LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.turnierLayout);
        

        TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
        textView1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textView1.setText("programmatically created TextView1");
        textView1.setBackgroundColor(0xff66ff66); // hex color 0xAARRGGBB
        textView1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);// in pixels (left, top, right, bottom)
        lLayout.addView(textView1);

        // Add textview 2
        TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10); // (left, top, right, bottom)
        textView2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        textView2.setText("programmatically created TextView2");
        textView2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
        textView2.setBackgroundColor(0xffffdbdb); // hex color 0xAARRGGBB
        lLayout.addView(textView2);
    }

}
```

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TurnierActiviy"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/turnierLayout">
</LinearLayout>
```

I only get a blank screen every time.

Can you help me with this problem?

Thank you :)

Best Regards.

Comment: I checked it ,it is working fine but without this line >> recentView = findViewById(R.id.txt_welcome);

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel a little bit dumb now :o

Comment: It is ok we all faced such situations))